# How to jump into bootloader in Ada?

Tags: embedded, ada

I am writing embedded code in Ada. I want to jump into bootloader code which is located at address 0x0E00. I am trying to use following code:

```
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with System;

package AVR.bootloader is

   procedure Call;
   pragma No_Return(Call);
   pragma Import (Assembler,Call);
   for Call'Address use System'To_Address (16#0E00#);

end AVR.bootloader;
```

The problem is this does not work.

Edit: I want to do a following C equivalent:

```
void (*boot)(void)=0x0E00;
```

Comment: The eternal question: **How does it "not work"?**

Comment: 1. How to do that? 2. How does it not work? 3. How is it possible I didn't thought about it!? I think the problem might in pragma Import  there's nothing to link.

Comment: What I mean by "How does it not work" is: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a small experiment on this Macbook Pro, and your code seems to do what you meant it to; I modified the code to read

```
with System;

procedure Bootloader is

   procedure Call;
   pragma No_Return (Call);
   pragma Import (Assembler, Call);
   for Call'Address use System'To_Address (16#0E00#);

begin
   Call;
end Bootloader;
```

and when I compile with `gnatmake -c -u -f -S bootloader.adb` the saved assembler is

```
        .text
        .globl __ada_bootloader
__ada_bootloader:
LFB1:
        pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
        subq    $16, %rsp
LCFI2:
        movq    $3584, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        call    *%rax
        leave
LCFI3:
        ret
[...]
```

which looks hopeful, though I’m not familiar enough with asm to know.

Running it under gdb I get (after a lot of chatter)

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/simon/tmp/bootloader 
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++........................ done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000e00
0x0000000000000e00 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000e00 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0xe00
#1  0x0000000100000d93 in main (argc=1, argv=140734799805048, envp=140734799805064) at /Users/simon/tmp/b~bootloader.adb:121
#2  0x0000000100000bf4 in start ()
```

which looks even more hopeful.

Perhaps your AVR compiler isn’t code-generating properly?

Comment: What i got was:
lds r30, 0x0000
lds r31, 0x0000
icall
I installed clean environment (virtual system, only GNAT) and it seem to work now! Strange, but problem is now solved. Thank you for the experiment it really helped.

Comment: You’d think one of those `0x0000`’s must have been `0x0e00`! Good to know it’s OK now.

Answer (score 2):

Since normally a boot-loader runs on reset, the simplest method is to force a processor reset.  A boot-loader may reasonably assume that it is running on an uninitialised system in reset state and may perform initialisation that is not valid on an already initialised system, so forcing a reset is the safest method.

Your processor may have a reset instruction or a reset controller that can perform this directly.  Failing that it may have a watchdog timer that can generate a reset. Start the watchdog timer with a suitably short time-out and let it run without servicing it.

Comment: I am currently using watchdog but this solution do not satisfy me. I would like to disable bootloader at reset and call it from within main program. Bootloader must be located at specific address to operate properly. I would like to avoid writing inline assembly and stick to clean solution.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just ignorant, but how do you intend to get to your main program without running a Bootloader first? Doesn't the Bootloader *have* to be run at reset, else your system won't load? Can you explain what you were trying to achieve in your question? I know you've accepted an answer, I'd just like to understand it better.

Comment: In many systems bootloader is loading system code from some sort of external memory into operating memory. In my case I have a simple embedded system where bootloader is used to program a non-volatile program memory (same name a bit different function). I do not want to run bootloader on every reset because it takes time to get into main loop. The device will drive a process which should be uninterrupted, even if device will hang. In such situation watchdog will cause reset. Still I want to program it without physical access.

Comment: @Tokamak:  In many microcontrollers it is possible to distinguish between a power-on reset and a watchdog reset.  Your bootloader could use that to skip directly to the application code rather than initiate any programming operation.  Jumping directly into the bootloader from the application is unsafe because the microcontroller is not in a known default state.

Comment: Unfortunately in Atmel AVR Atmega devices it is not possible. I feel pretty confident in terms of MCUs unlike Ada (It's required at my university).

Comment: I beg to differ, I just looked at the data-sheet and on reset the MCUCSR register indicates the reset source.

Comment: I was wrong and you are right. The MCUSCR register is present at my device and I can modify bootloader to distinct reset condition. Thank you for correcting my lack of knowledge.